# Multiple Trigger on single Field in fields.yaml (OctoberCMS)

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm currently trying to add a trigger to a form with multiple trigger on single field.

In my case when select **intetnal** it triggers **contenttype** and than it shows **video** or **article** based on selection. And after doing all things when I will select **external** from **link** it will not trigger to close contenttype

**I am trying but not working :**

```
   link:
        label: 'Internal Or External Link'
        options:
            internal: Internal
            external: External
        span: full
        default: internal
        required: 1
        type: dropdown
        comment: 'Select Link Type'
    external_link:
        label: 'External Link'
        span: full
        trigger:
            action: show
            field: link
            condition: 'value[external]'
        type: text
        comment: 'Enter External Link'
    content_type:
        label: 'Content Type'
        options:
            video: Video
            article: Article
        span: full
        trigger:
            action: show
            field: link
            condition: 'value[internal]'
        type: dropdown
        comment: 'Select Content Type'
    videolink:
        label: 'Video Link'
        span: full
        trigger:
            action: show
            field: content_type
            condition: 'value[video]'
        type: text
        comment: 'Enter Video Link'
    article_content:
        label: 'Article Content'
        size: large
        span: full
        trigger:
            action: show
            field: content_type
            condition: 'value[article]'
        type: richeditor
        comment: 'Add Article Content'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, you can do it but we need to make sure `content_type` get empty on hide

so, we can do this

```
external_link:
    label: 'External Link'
    span: full
    trigger:
        action: hide
        field: link
        condition: 'value[internal]'
    type: text
    comment: 'Enter External Link'
content_type:
    label: 'Content Type'
    emptyOption: -- select a status --
    options:
        video: Video
        article: Article
    span: full
    trigger:
        action: hide|empty
        field: link
        condition: 'value[external]'
    type: dropdown
    comment: 'Select Content Type'
```

we can use `multiple actions` to get our job done. and yes we also need to add `emptyOption` for `content_type` to make it empty.

so when `link` value is `external` then it will `hide` and `empty` field `content_type` so in order to that reaction `videolink OR article_content` can not get its value as `content_type` will be `empty` so they also `hide with that`.

> **For the sake of simplicity** I am putting diff images **so you get better idea what I have changed** :)

[image]

> **<= left** old one **right =>** new one

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: setting`empty` does the trick if you have nested / multiple fields conditions.